# Responsive rollover image

Tags: responsive, rollover

I am trying to make a rollover image responsive to browser width and height. Here is the current code:

```
'<a href="google.com"><img src="http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_zpsekucjvgf.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg'" /></a>'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! We try our best to answer peoples questions when they are well thought out and show evidence of research and show code. Please read the following documentation http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can do something like this:

```
<a href="google.com"><img id="myImage" src="http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_zpsekucjvgf.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg'" /></a>
<script>
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  document.getElementById("myImage").width = w;
</script>
```

This would adjust the image width to the inner width of the browser window. If you want to adjust by height, use the window.innerHeight property instead. You can write some logic if you want to adjust your image by the smallest of the two in relation to your image.

Or, if you want to do it inline:

```
<a href="google.com"><img src="http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_zpsekucjvgf.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o535/DanielleStateAuto/360_vid_033017_A_still_zpskfsuzshi.jpg'" width="window.innerWidth"/></a>
```

would work also, but it would be hard to add additional logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

A modern better practice to this would be non-JS / pure CSS. There are a few methods to achieving this, here's one:

```
<a href="#"><div class="myimg"></div></a>
```

---

```
   .myimg { 
    width:80%;
    height:200px;
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/bc/4e/38/bc4e386f24997b6f8c4c1f8ce96a7cef.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.myimg:hover { 
    background: url(http://img00.deviantart.net/4ec1/i/2013/017/5/b/blue_eyed_huskey_by_ashleysmithphoto-d5rsvt2.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dLc5u1ku/). Obviously, you would configure the above CSS properties to your preference / project.